# VSCode SSH - Quick Open and Find in Files stopped working on remote

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I use VSCode over ssh connections and one particular server no longer works with Quick Open.

When I connect I can see all the files and folders and open and edit but no quick open. I tried from another machine so believe it's an issue on the remote machine rather than local. Also I can connect to other remotes and it works.

If I run vscode over a VNC on the remote quick open works. Any idea what could be happening? Does the remote need something that may have stopped working?

Find in files also doesn't work and extensions which need to scan files don't work. I scanned for an exclusions and ignores but even if I open a completely different folder on the remote quickfind doesn't work.

I'm out of ideas.

Connect to remote via ssh extension using VSCode and quikly open files with ctrl p.
Connected but no quick open.